# Xamarin IOS SIGSEV crash DZNEmptyDataset

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am getting a SIGSEV crash while executing DZNEmptyDataset code on my Xamarin iOS project when running on a simulator. I am using a native ios library DZNEmptyDataSet.

the error is below

```
   Thread 0 Crashed:: tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
     0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000118a9cdd6 __pthread_kill + 10
     1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000118ad4787 pthread_kill + 90
     2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000118816fd7 abort + 129
     3   com.johnamcruz.Balln           0x000000010be4192e mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 574 (mini-exceptions.c:2420)
     4   com.johnamcruz.Balln           0x000000010bdbb24a mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception + 90 (exceptions-amd64.c:808)
     5   com.johnamcruz.Balln           0x000000010be4eade mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 446 (mini-runtime.c:2883)
     6   libsystem_platform.dylib       0x0000000118abfbba _sigtramp + 26
     7   ???                            000000000000000000 0 + 0
     8   com.johnamcruz.Balln           0x000000010bd54c08 -[UIScrollView(DZNEmptyDataSet) dzn_reloadEmptyDataSet] + 33 (UIScrollView+EmptyDataSet.m:413)
     9   com.johnamcruz.Balln           0x000000010bd5562d dzn_original_implementation + 150 (UIScrollView+EmptyDataSet.m:577)
     10  com.apple.UIKit                0x0000000114cee302 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 34
```

My code is below. I am refreshing the tableview in ViewDidAppear method and setting delegates to null on ViewDidDisappear method.

```
    public async override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        await RefreshGames();
        FacebookLogin();

        TableView.SetEmptyDataSetSource(new EmptyGameDataSource());
        TableView.TableFooterView = new UIView();
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        TableView.SetEmptyDataSetSource(null);
        TableView.SetEmptyDataSetDelegate(null);
        TableView.Source = null;
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    }

    public async Task RefreshGames()
    {
        MTMBProgressHUD.ShowHUD(View, true);
        var datasource = new GameDataSource(await gameLogic.GetAllGamesAsync());
        datasource.RowDeleted += async (sender, e) => 
        {
            await gameLogic.DeleteGameAsync(e);
            await RefreshGames();
        };
        TableView.Source = datasource;
        MTMBProgressHUD.HideHUD(View, true);
    }
```

Comment: Did you create your own binding for this library? There is a component on Xamarin's component store for this library, perhaps try using that? See: https://components.xamarin.com/view/dznemptydataset

Comment: I am using the binding from components.xamarin.com/dznemptydataset and thats whats causing the problem. Have you used that particular binding before? @jgoldberger

Comment: No I have not used that library. I'll see if I can reproduce the issue and get a bug report filed if need be.

Comment: OK, so I tried but could not reproduce this issue. Note I did not use your code as there are missing bits. In the code you posted, I do not see you calling SetEmptyDataSetDelegate to set the delegate, I only see you setting it to null in ViewWillDisappear, could that be the issue? Also you are adding an event handler (dataSource.RowDeleted) in RefreshGames, and each time you call that method, you are adding the event handler again. This can cause issues. You should unsubscribe to the event before adding it again, or subscribe to the event somewhere else that is not called repeatedly.

Comment: Anyway, on my end, working from this sample [1] and adding the Component and implementing the EmptyDataSetSource and EmptyDataSetDelegate everything worked as expected. [1] https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/WorkingWithTables/

Comment: It didnt need the SetEmptyDataSetDelegate because it assumes the default emptyDataSetDelegate if its not added. Can you send me your sample? @jgoldberger thanks for you help

Comment: for your sample are you loading static data or pulling data from a web service. for my refreshGame method, i am loading the data from web service and populating the TableView.Source. @jgoldberger

Comment: I was loading static data. Here's a link to the quick sample I tested: https://microsoft-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jgolde_microsoft_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=oEmPy43lVvh163Thb+nKY7C2U9EMb9lWVS64Hu4a6Z4=&docid=2_19ed5e651eec94d1ba64a4f2a874c6723&rev=1

Comment: Any luck with this? I've managed to get this working now with no issue but I do notice this library is very out of date. 400+ days since an update.